# Rails 3 Mailing Lists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very interested in learning more about Rails 3 and following the latest trends and news. Thus, i would like to ask whether there are some well known mailing lists that it's really worth following.

Comment: Could be a community wiki I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.rubyflow.com/ and http://www.rubyinside.com/ are the two I follow (you can use RSS to subscribe)

Answer (score 0):

Being on StackOverflow is far better than any mailing list.  I can't say that I've found any lists that are very helpful.